# Default value in Constructor showing error in Kotlin

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I'm doing same as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601611/kotlin-default-constructor) and [here](https://www.callicoder.com/kotlin-classes-objects-constructors-initializers/#default-values-in-the-constructor) but showing error

this is my class with its `primary constructor` with no `secondary constructor` no `init` block.

```
class RowSubTShirtViewModel(private val subTShirtAdapter: SubTShirtAdapter, val context: TShirtActivity,
                            val tShirtBean: CommonItemBean, private val parentPosition: Int, private val position: Int) : BaseObservable(), TShirtActivity.setSelectionSubRow {}
```

creating object like `val vm=RowSubTShirtViewModel()` giving error

> - Create abstract function 'RowSubTShirtViewModel'
> - Create function 'RowSubTShirtViewModel'
> - Create secondary constructor
> - No value passed for parameter

Comment: Dear @farhana, regarding [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21764432), please note that Stack Overflow has a policy regarding [meta-tag:link-only-answers], and even a predefined comment to deal with such cases. See ["_**any link-only answer should be deleted.** It is not an answer._"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251613/1033581)

Answer (score 2):

You need explicitly pass parameters to primary constructor:

```
//init params
val subTShirtAdapter = ...
val context = ...
val tShirtBean = ...
val parentPosition = ...
val position = ...

//init viewModel
val vm = RowSubTShirtViewModel(subTShirtAdapter, context, tShirtBean, parentPosition, position)
```

Unless you assign default values to params, e.g.:

```
class RowSubTShirtViewModel(private val subTShirtAdapter = YourAdapter(),...)
```

In your case you can do something like this:

```
class RowSubTShirtViewModel(val context: TShirtActivity, 
    private val subTShirtAdapter: SubTShirtAdapter, 
    val tShirtBean: CommonItemBean, 
    private val parentPosition: Int = 0, 
    private val position: Int = 0) : BaseObservable(), TShirtActivity.setSelectionSubRow {}

// and then create an instance
val vm = RowSubTShirtViewModel(yourContext, yourAdapter, yourShirtBean)
```

Comment: I'm exactly doing as the tutorial do and as answer tells. can you please explain where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you just missed assign default parameter, see my edited answer.

Comment: if i arrange parameter in order , and context would be first then it will be okay.

Comment: But in your case I think there is no reason to create RowSubTShirtViewModel with default parameters, because they should be initialized in the top layer (where the instance of RowSubTShirtViewModel is created)

Comment: what does the top layer mean?

Comment: I arranged parameters and context is  first and I pass context and i have not sent rest of the parameters  then still it is asking for parameters.

Comment: I mean function where the instance of RowSubTShirtViewModel is created

Comment: I created the object in the method of `Activity` and this class is of Adapter's `view model`.

Comment: if I made a secondary constructor with no parameter then still will ask for `primary call expected`.

Comment: I edited my answer, please check, maybe it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You are not using [default arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments) in your constructor. If you like to use, it should look like

```
class RowSubTShirtViewModel(
    private val subTShirtAdapter: SubTShirtAdapter = defaultSubTShirtAdapter,
    val context: TShirtActivity = defultContext,
    val tShirtBean: CommonItemBean = defaultTShirtBean,
    private val parentPosition: Int = defaultParentPosition,
    private val position: Int = defaultPosition) : BaseObservable(), TShirtActivity.setSelectionSubRow {}
```

Comment: if I arrange parameter in order, and context would be first then it will be okay.

Comment: I made default argument function for that class showing no compile time error but on runtime showing KNP. my aim to call interface method from activity and that class has implemented the interface.